# I want to use php to scrape the input value readonly value using simple html dom, I keep getting a blank return

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to scrape the readonly value from the following code below inside this input form, I am using php with simple html dom but I keep getting a blank reply. what can I do to make it give me that value.

```
<input id="copy-video-embed" type="text" readonly value="<iframe src=&quot;https://www.example.com/embedframe/52285029&quot; frameborder=0 width=510 height=400 scrolling=no allowfullscreen=allowfullscreen></iframe>" class="form-control">
```

so I have tried to the code below but does not seem to work

```
$node = $stuff->find('input[type=text]' , 0)->plaintext ;  print_r($node) ;
```

Comment: Try use value instead of plaintext. $stuff->find('input[type=text]' , 0)->value

Comment: i tried to add "value" and also "readonly value" , didnt work, still returns blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `find` to get a part of your HTML you get the attributes as class variable so you can use `href` or `value` to get the value.

```
$node = $stuff->find('input[type=text]' , 0)->value;
```

something like this.

https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm

Here are some good examples.

Comment: i have been on that page before, i could not see any clear examples for input forms and how to havest the data

Comment: You were right, instead of just identifying the input field as text, i gave it the ID and it worked  find('input#copy-video-embed',0)->value